# Django custom AuthenticationForm fields

Tags: python, django

I want to use `email` and `password` fields only to authenticate, 
but it seems Django forces me to get `username` field. 
I tried to use `username` to login by adding `username` field to my `User` model, 
but it also ended with `valid=Unknown` 

I've read Django docs custom `AuthenticationForm` guide, 
and it ended without making custom `AuthenticationForm` ...

`view`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate

from .forms import UserLoginForm


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(f"{request.POST=}")
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        print(f"{form=}")
        if form.is_valid():
            print("  form valid")
            user = login(request, form)
            print(f"  user login {user}")
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm()
    
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

`UserLoginForm`

```
class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password', )
    
    _base_attrs = {
        'class': 'form-control', 
        'placeholder': '', 
    }
    
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs=_base_attrs
        )
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs=_base_attrs
        )
    )
```

`User`

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="email", 
        max_length=255, 
        unique=True, 
    )
    is_leadership = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    objects = UserManager()
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('password', )
```

`email_backend`

```
class EmailBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        
        user = UserModel.objects.get(email=email)
        
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        
        return None
```

`settings`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['account.backends.EmailBackend']
```

[image]

And it keeps give me the result above
which has `valid=Unknown` and `fields=(username;email;password;)`

is there any method to force fields not include 'username'? 
or make it valid only with email and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
user = login(request, form)
```

login() requires a request and a user, not a form.  You can get the user by calling authenticate before logging the user on. Try somnehting like:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(f"{request.POST=}")
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        print(f"{form=}")
        if form.is_valid():
            print("  form valid")
            #get cleaned form fields        
            email= form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            #authenticate the user
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            login(request, user)
  ...
```

Another thing I find useful, especially if you are not using default auth forms, is making your 'account' app the first one listed in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS so it finds yours before the default ones, eg,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
"account",
"django.contrib.admin",
"django.contrib.auth",
...
```

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account', 
    
    # Django defaults
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    # APPS
    'homepage', 
    'chatting', 
]`
 changed like this and still the same...

Comment: Found another issue and updated answer

Comment: I gave up dealing with emails and just added `username` field to my user model... And now my resolved view really does authenticate and then does login! If I had known this earlier, I would use email to login. thank you for the help